# Linq IQueryable variables

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Hi i have a function that should return me a string but what is is doing is bringing me back the sql expression that i am using on the database
what have i done wrong

```
 public static IQueryable XMLtoProcess(string strConnection)
    {
        Datalayer.HameserveDataContext db = new HameserveDataContext(strConnection);

        var xml = from x in db.JobImports
                  where x.Processed == false
                  select new { x.Content };
        return xml;

    }
```

this is the code sample

this is what i should be getting back

```
<PMZEDITRI TRI_TXNNO="11127" TRI_TXNSEQ="1" TRI_CODE="600" TRI_SUBTYPE="1" TRI_STATUS="Busy" TRI_CRDATE="2008-02-25T00:00:00.0000000-00:00" TRI_CRTIME="54540" TRI_PRTIME="0" TRI_BATCH="" TRI_REF="" TRI_CPY="main" C1="DEPL" C2="007311856/001" C3="14:55" C4="CUB2201" C5="MR WILLIAM HOGG" C6="CS12085393" C7="CS" C8="Blocked drain" C9="Scheme: CIS Home Rescue edi tests" C10="MR WILLIAM HOGG" C11="74 CROMARTY" C12="OUSTON" C13="CHESTER LE STREET" C14="COUNTY DURHAM" C15="" C16="DH2 1JY" C17="" C18="" C19="" C20="" C21="CIS" C22="0018586965 ||" C23="BD" C24="W/DE/BD" C25="EX-DIRECTORY" C26="" C27="/" C28="CIS Home Rescue" C29="CIS Home Rescue Plus Insd" C30="Homeserve Claims Management Ltd|Upon successful completion of this repair the contractor must submit an itemised and costed Homeserve Claims Management Ltd Job Sheet." N1="79.9000" N2="68.0000" N3="11.9000" N4="0" N5="0" N6="0" D1="2008-02-25T00:00:00.0000000-00:00" T2="EX-DIRECTORY" T4="Blocked drain" TRI_SYSID="9" TRI_RETRY="3" TRI_RETRYTIME="0" />
```

can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1):

i have sorted it by using this

```
var xml = db.JobImports.Single(x => x.Processed == false);
return xml.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your method is of type `IQueryable`
2. You should not directly `return xml;`
   Convert it to `return xml.ToList()` or whatever you want it to be (In your case `xml.ToString()`
3. Change your method type to `String`

If you directly return `xml` it'll be of type `IQueryable`

Comment: i have tried this and im still getting the expression comming back to me

Comment: instead of selecting  new { x.Content }; try to select XElement.. I'm sure that you will the out you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to force the query to be executed before returning the result, e.g. like this:

```
return xml.ToList();
```

This is necessary since your LINQ query is executed lazily, i.e. not until you actually access the result. Your code currently doesn't do this.